# Does a power that says “targets in an area” let you choose them?

Tags: star-wars-saga-edition, targeting

In Star Wars Saga edition, when a power says “targets in an area”, can you select which are hit?

Comment: I don't see how the flamethrower works any different from a Force Slam. Can you elaborate on precisely what the question is?

Comment: I've removed that section of the question, it wasn't super helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "Force Powers" section does not detail "aiming a force power", however, this is a d20 game, so you can refer to [aiming a spell](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/magicOverview/spellDescriptions.htm#aimingASpell) or [aiming a power](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/psionic/psionicPowersOverview.htm#aimingAPower).

*Force Slam Targets:*

> All targets within a 6-square cone and within line of sight.

For cone,

> A cone-shaped spell shoots away from you in a quarter-circle in the direction you designate.

Yes, you choose the direction of the cone but it emanates from you. 
[image]

UPDATE:

> can you select which are hit?

In d20, there are options for spells, specifically, the prestige class [Archmage](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/prestigeClasses/archmage.htm#) has the ability [Mastery of Shaping](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/prestigeClasses/archmage.htm#masteryofShaping) that allows the caster to creating 5' square spaces within the spell’s area or effect that are not subject to the spell. Similarly, the [Sculpt Spell](http://www.realmshelps.net/charbuild/feat/Sculpt_Spell) feat allows you to modify the area. There really isn't anything like this in the Saga edition of Star Wars, but a GM could incorporate something like it for the force.

Feat: **Force Shape**

Prerequisite: Force Sensitivity.

Effect: You can alter the shape of your area force effects. The alteration consists of creating spaces within the force power's area or effect that are not subject to the force effect. The minimum dimension for these spaces is a 5-foot cube.

Comment: This is what I'm asking. I know in some systems you can, others you can't. I don't see it specified in the system, and the word "targets" makes me feel like I should be able to pick. My flamethrower reference was because "picking targets with a flamethrower" sounds ridiculous!

Comment: I had hoped for an answer from the SW rulebook, but the links to the D20 system are a reasonable approximation, and seem reasonable in game, given the things we're talking about. Thanks!